# My mom uses dish washing detergent to wash her tomatoes and I'm freaked out it'll seep in to the tomatoes

Tags: fruit

Is washing tomatoes, apples, oranges etc. with dish washing detergent normal? She's literally unmovable no matter how I tell her she still keeps doing it. I am freaked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it 'normal'?
No, it's somewhat germophobic behaviour.

Will it do you any harm?
No, so long as it's rinsed well. If you can't smell it or taste it, you'll be fine. It's just like leaving your dishes to drain rather than drying with a tea towel. Even if you can still smell or taste it, though gross, it's still not concentrated enough to worry about.

Comment: I don't understand how washing vegetables with detergent compares to leaving your dishes to drain.  Can you please explain?

Comment: I think he's assuming the dishes were washed in dish washing detergent. So any residue left on the produce would be the same as the residue left on the clean dishes that you eat off.

Answer (score 4):

Dish washing liquid is quite mild and safe.

As long as she properly rinses the produces, you should be ok.